# Computing the minimal polynomial in an arbitrary field

Tags: linear-algebra

The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29#Computation) on minimal polynomials includes an explanation on how to compute the minimal polynomial recursively.

Here is the last step:

> The minimal polynomial $\mu_T$ is the product of $\mu_{T,v}$ and the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to $\operatorname{Im}(\mu_{T,v}(T))$.

I can see how it could be proven over $\mathbb{R}$: by using the fact that for any $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ we have $\mathbb{R}^n = \ker A \oplus \operatorname{im} A^T$. But I'm not sure how to generalize it to an arbitrary field.

Is the recursive algorithm still valid over an arbitrary field? Any hints on how to prove the validity of the last step?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood it correctly, this should effectively just be the rank-nullity theorem: the dimension of a matrix is the sum of its rank and its nullity (the dimension of its nullspace).

a.k.a. the first isomorphism theorem: the image of a linear map is the quotient of its domain by its kernel.

Comment: The algorithm needs strict equality to work.

Comment: The problem is that we're interested in birestrictions of a linear operator on both the kernel and the image.

Comment: This is neither rank-nullity, nor the first isomorphism theorem. In fact you need to use the definition of minimal polynomial somewhere. See my answer for how it arises.

Answer (score 0):

In the cited formula $v$ is some vector, and $\mu_{T,v}$ is the minimal degree monic polynomial such that $\mu_{T,v}[T](v)=0$, which ensures that it divides the global minimal polynomial $\mu_T$. If one puts $Q=\mu_T/\mu_{T,v}$, then since $\mu_T=Q\mu_{T,v}$ one has $Q[T]\circ\mu_{T,v}[T]=0$; therefore $Q$ is an an annihilating polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to $\operatorname{Im}(\mu_{T,v}[T])$. On the other hand if $Q'$ were a lower degree (nonzero) annihilating polynomial of that restriction, then one would have
$$
  (Q'\mu_{T,v})[T]=Q'[T]\circ\mu_{T,v}[T]=0
$$
with $\deg(Q'\mu_{T,v})<\deg(Q\mu_{T,v})=\deg(\mu_T)$, contradicting the minimality of $\mu_T$. So (the monic polynomial) $Q$ is in fact the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to $\operatorname{Im}(\mu_{T,v}[T])$.